# laravel - how to show resource data in view as an html

Tags: php, json, laravel

hi i have a resource that returns the API JSON correctly now I want to show that data in HTML like the Laravel home page inside a MacBook SVG how can I access that JSON in my controller and send it to view because I already copied the MacBook and the code snippet of laravel.com so here is my code :
resource :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

and controller which is working fine as api now :

```
    try {
        $data = Accommodation::paginate(15);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        throw new HttpException(500, $e->getMessage());
    }
    return new AccommodationResource($data);
```

now instead of that return of resource i want to return a view and send the $data as a json to it

Comment: `return view('your.view.name')->with($yourData);`?

Comment: it wont bring it from a resource i tried that already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
return view('your_view', ['data'=> json_encode($data)] );
```